# Arduino 0-10V input

Tags: arduino, sensor, industrial

I have read [Arduino Mega 0 - 10V analog input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21963/arduino-mega-0-10v-analog-input) for Arduino analog inputs, but I want to make the circuit for industrial use. I have read that an analog opto isolator should be good.

Can I get any advice on how to design it for industrial use?
We are using a Portenta C33 high density connector which has 0-3.3V analog pins.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of "industrial use?"  There's "industrial" next to the steel smelting arc furnace, then there's "industrial" inside some babied piece of equipment in the lab of a food processing plant - and all kinds of stuff in between.  What are you tring to the protect the Arduino from, besides "10V is too much for the 3.3V input."

Comment: I meant for industrial for long time use.

Answer (score 2):

An Arduino is a hobbyist module. It is not an industrial product.

If you surround it with the required 'stuff' to bring it to actual industrial standards (say, to be as hardened and reliable as an AB PLC) the Arduino circuitry will be a trivial part of that.

Arduino themselves offer [PLC-like properly packaged products](https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/datasheets/AFX00001-AFX00002-AFX00003-datasheet.pdf) based on STM32H7 series MCUs. I have no knowledge of whether they actually measure up. If your application can cause safety hazards in any way or cause substantial damage to property by malfunctioning you should investigate this. They do have 0-10V analog inputs as standard.

Comment: Hi!
Yes I know that. We are using Arduino (Pro)Portenta C33 in this case, not a hobbyist model